# Clicking Chat Button With Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am trying to click chat button with selenium, which appears in about 3 seconds after the page is loaded, it does not have id or name, I have tried implicit and explicit wait, Xpath, CSS selector, tag name, almost everything. It just can not find an element. I think selenium does not perceive the button as a part of an HTML. I need your help...

Link : https://shopiqa.com/

My code:

```
TestTools.driver.get("https://shopiqa.com/");
TestTools.driver.manage().window().maximize();
TestTools.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
TestTools.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"desktop-start\"]/button")).click();
```

Image:
[image: Tring to click envite button]

Comment: What version of selenium?

Comment: version: 3.141.59

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chat button is present inside an **iframe**.You need to switch it first in order to access the `Chat button`.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt`() and following css selector.

Then scroll the page and then

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `elementToBeClickable`() and css selector.

```
driver.navigate().to("https://shopiqa.com/"); 
driver.manage().window().maximize();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe.envite-iframe")));
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#desktop-start>button"))).click();
```

**Browser snapshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your case, there is an iFrame. first, you can switch your driver that particular iFrame then you can perform click() method.

For your reference, you can refer below code:

```
driver.get("https://shopiqa.com/");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='envite-iframe']")));
WebElement iframeElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='envite-iframe']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframeElement);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='desktop-start']/button")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='desktop-start']/button")).click();
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
//*[@id="desktop-start"]/button/p
```